# jquery window.resize not working when i make the screen less

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a jQuery function which I only want to load when the screen is bigger than 767. The code works when I load the page (jQuery running above 767, not under 767). It also works when I resize the screen bigger (starts running above 767).

But when I have the running jQuery and resize my screen under 767, my function is still running, even though in my code only above 767 is written. Could you help me with this issue?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 767){
        //my function
    };

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() > 767){
        //my function
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the [`$( window ).resize(function() {});`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

so you code woulde be like :

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
 if($(window).width() > 767){
    //my function
 };});
```

Comment: can show me the code that you wana excute when screen resize !